# Feasibility of extract/download PowerBI .pbit file and automatically save it to Sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powerbi, power-automate

I am new to PowerBI with little to no knowledge. I do have some expertise in SharePoint.

I have a task to download .pbit files from a dataset in a workspace and upload that into a Sharepoint site document library and this needs to be Automated so I was wondering if there is anyway I can achieve this using  powershell script.

I am also looking for any alternate solution for this using Power Automate.

Any advise or suggestion is appreciated.